# Best practice for attaching low voltage conduit to cedar siding?

Tags: conduit, siding, cedar

I'm a little lost.

I'm trying to run PVC conduit (for data lines) from my basement to the attic on the outside of my house. What's the best way to attach it to my beveled cedar siding?

Comment: A word of caution: Cedar splits very easily. I recommend you pre-drill all of your holes before putting any screws in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's simple, just use PVC conduit clamps sized for the conduit you are using. Place them on the highest part of the bevel, every 4 feet or so. Since product recommendations are OT here, just search, any big box store will carry them.

Comment: Wouldn't that cause a water hazard, and future rot behind my siding if i drill into it?

Comment: @LostHammer Screwing in the clamps with short screws should not let water through; use a very small pilot hole not drilled very deep so the screw is tight in the wood. In any case, siding is expected to handle a bit of moisture getting behind it, letting it run down and out. Just use screws rated for use with cedar so they don't react. There are plenty of fancy polymer-coated or similar weather "proof" screws now available.

Comment: @LostHammer -- you should be leaving a bit of an air gap between your siding and your WRB *anyway*...

Comment: An extra detail: the screws should be long enough to bite into the sheathing behind the siding, that is needed to actually support anything. A little 1/2" screw or something only into the siding won't cut it